# Failed to connect from jdeveloper to weblogic server jsr 160 failed

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper, weblogic12c

I'm trying to connect from Jdeveloper to a remote Weblogic server. This is what I get when testing the connection.

[image: Connection]

Some say that one should disable jdeveloper's proxy settings. I did so, and it didn't change anything. Any help !

[image: Proxy]

Comment: This provided me with a solution: "Try to run your JDeveloper as administrator (it's a common 'mistake' for Windows users)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the server's host name in the "hosts" file in the client's operating system.
Next time when you add an application server in jdeveloper, don't input the ip, type the hostname instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run your JDeveloper as administrator (it's a common 'mistake' for Windows users).
If that doesn't work you should read this blog post: http://sathyam-soa.blogspot.be/2012/06/jdeveloper-11g-cannot-establish-app.html

Answer (score 0):

One additional possible issue is when the domain is running in a docker container and you had the Dockerfile expose the AdminServer port externally, which then means it is proxied via the host system. In that case, you want to point WebLogic Hostname not to the IP or hostname of the container, but of the physical machine instead.

So you run the netstat command, like:

```
    host> netstat -nap | grep 7001
    tcp     1165      0 172.17.42.1:35464           172.17.0.1:7001             CLOSE_WAIT  32752/java          
    tcp        1      0 172.17.42.1:33738           172.17.0.1:7001             CLOSE_WAIT  32752/java          
    tcp        1      0 172.17.42.1:33746           172.17.0.1:7001             CLOSE_WAIT  32752/java          
    tcp     1165      0 172.17.42.1:35123           172.17.0.1:7001             CLOSE_WAIT  32752/java          
    tcp        0      0 :::7001                     :::*                        LISTEN      -
```

You see the interim / proxy listed above, 172.17.42.1. You can check via the ifconfig command and see the docker proxy is that IP address:

```
    host> ifconfig
    docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 56:84:7A:FE:97:99  
              inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:429422 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:356600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:228869726 (218.2 MiB)  TX bytes:322146511 (307.2 MiB)
```

That tells you that there is a proxy in the mix, so instead of using the hostname / IP address of the container running the Admin Server, use the hostname of the machine running the docker container and the Admin Server port. Then the Test should succeed.