# Error creating an Application Server connection in JDeveloper

Tags: weblogic12c, jdeveloper, oracle-bpm-suite

## Background

I am using the Oracle JDeveloper Studio with SOA installed as my IDE.  In JDeveloper I want to create a connection to a remote Weblogic server.

> The *remote* server is running on my local machine, and I refer to it as remote to distinguish it from the *Integrated Weblogic Server* that comes with JDeveloper.

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013673/failed-to-connect-from-jdeveloper-to-weblogic-server-jsr-160-failed) answer I attempted to add the following lines to the Windows 10 host file:

```
#
127.0.0.10 localhost2
::1 localhost2
```

These two pictures show the Application Server setup in JDeveloper: [Picture 1](http://%20https://ibb.co/RPmC0r0), [Picture 2](https://ibb.co/vj5Q3nz)

However I still receive the following error:

```
Server excetion is :
Connection refused from server
```

> When create new server on random port such as 7013 and 7014 for ssl, test connection return:

```
Testing HTTP Authentication            ... failed
Connection refused: connect
Testing JSR-160 Runtime                ... failed
Cannot establish connection.
Testing JSR-160 DomainRuntime          ... skipped
Testing JSR-88                         ... skipped
Testing JSR-88-LOCAL                   ... skipped
Testing Server MBeans Model            ... skipped
Testing App Controller                 ... skipped
Testing JSR-88-DEP-MGR                 ... skipped
Testing JSR-88-DEP-MGR-LOCAL           ... skipped
Testing JNDI                           ... skipped
Testing JSR-160 Edit                   ... skipped
Testing HTTP                           ... failed
Connection refused: connect

0 of 12 tests successful.
```

Can anyone suggest some troubleshooting steps here?

Comment: hey, thanks for your question. We like for all information including error messages to be typed up, and not screenshotted

Comment: @f.khantsis sure,here you are

Comment: If you haven't worked  this issue  please take a look army response. If it doesnt fix your issue update your question with a PostScript and ill update mine accordingly

Answer (score 1):

## Clarification

I need to clarify a few points to guide you to the correct answer.

- Are you sure this is a separate Weblogic server running on localhost, not the Integrated Weblogic Server?
- Are you sure the Integrated Weblogic server is not running?
- Are you sure the Weblogic server you are attempting to connect to is running?

## Troubleshooting

### General Recommendations

- Always run JDeveloper as Administrator
- Located an utilize the *-diagnostic.log file and the standard out file
- Utilize the JPS utility to see if the WLS process is running
- Utilize the EM console to see what interface your server is listening on

### Integrated Weblogic or Standalone Weblogic

Firstly, because you are new to Oracle SOA I need you to clarify if you have a Weblogic server installed locally **separate** from your Oracle BPM Studio ( JDeveloper ) IDE.

> When creating a local SOA environment, JDeveloper comes with an Integrated Weblogic Server pre-installed.  You don't need to install the Weblogic server separately.

To determine if you have a standalone Weblogic server installed on your local machine you could do a few things.

- Do a search for `startWebLogic.cmd`.  If that file is somewhere other than beneath %APPDATA% you likely have a standalone server
- Secondly, with 11g ( maybe 12c ) you can check *Add or Remove Programs* to see if the installation is listed
- You could also check to see if it's running by running a `jps` command in command prompt. This shows all Java processes currently running, and your Weblogic server runs as as a Java process. It will look something like the following
  [image]
- If you see a suspicious process you can run a `jinfo <pid>` to get more information about the process
- You can also check Windows Services to see if you have a Weblogic service.

Most likely you don't even have a local Weblogic installed separate from JDeveloper's Integrated Server.  In that case, please read the following section.

## Integrated Weblogic Server

As stated before when you download Oracle BPM Studio ( JDeveloper with all the SOA plugins ) it comes with an Integrated server.

You first need to create a default domain and connection to this server.

1. **First, open the Application Server panel.**

   [image]
2. **You should now see the Application Server panel to the left side of your IDE**

   [image]

> Remember, generally you are not installing the server here, you are just connecting to a server that is already installed from your IDE.  The purpose being that you can deploy composites directly to the server from JDeveloper. Configuring the Integrated Server is a bit different, but the difference doesn't need to be explained here.

3. **Right click on "Application Servers" and click *New Application Server*.  This will display the following popup**

[image: List item]

4. **Now walk through the steps of creating the default domain and server connection**

   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Then test and finish.  You should not have an integrated weblogic server running.  To start the server you simply `run -> Start Integrated Weblogic Server`

[image]

If you `Windows -> log` you can see the server stdout and stderr rolling.

> On windows you can also find these logs on Windows 10 by navigating to `%APPDATA%\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.3.42.170820.0914\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs` in your system's file explorer.

## Standalone Server

If for whatever reason you aren't using the Integrated Weblogic Server and instead have a standalone installation of Weblogic on your local machine you would first need to find where your Middleware Home directory is.

> The environment variable is MW_HOME or ORACLE_HOME

Navigate to that directory and run `startWeblogic.cmd`.  Then tail the out file to see if if it starts successful.  From there, the process of creating a connection to the server in JDeveloper is no different than the steps listed above, except that you want to select "standalone" not "integrated".

## Final Thoughts

If you want to create the Integrated Server and have already failed several times I would try the following

1. Stop the Integrated Server (if its running) and delete the default domain
   [image]

   > Starting the server again (see above) will recreate the domain.
2. If that doesn't work delete the entire server connection and recreate.  You may also want to delete the *DefaultDomain* folder in your `%APPDATA%\JDeveloper` folder

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: (All the steps are executed in cmd as admin)

First, run set QS_TEMPLATE=G:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\common\templates\wls\oracle.soa_template.jar

Second, cd G:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin

Third, run qs_config.cmd, it will run an installer in which you'll have to enter a password for your server and please note that the port that worked for me is 7101 and 7102.

After the installer finishes, it will automatically run startWebLogic.cmd. Wait until you see line like this: "<Sep 27, 2023 11:16:55,443 PM EET> ".

I hope the answer helps you.