# I can't create an application server instance in JDeveloper

Tags: java, weblogic12c, soa, jdeveloper

I'm new in oracle Jdeveloper and I was trying to create an application and deploy it on an WeblogicIntegrated insatance. I tried creating the instance as shown in the screenshots: [image: 1st Step] Note: I tried both the standalone and integrated server options
[image: 2nd Step]
[image: 3rd Step][image: 4th Step]
[image: 5th Step]
[image: 6th Step].

Please be noted that I installed the jars shown in the following screenshot: [image: Installed Jars].

I tried following some youtube tutorials including: https://youtu.be/N4kMWBs-xOQ?si=IpLoyIheSYI2MlQf
and followed the provided solutions in the following question: [Error creating an Application Server connection in JDeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795765/error-creating-an-application-server-connection-in-jdeveloper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: (All the steps are executed in cmd as admin)

First, run set QS_TEMPLATE=G:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\common\templates\wls\oracle.soa_template.jar

Second, cd G:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin

Third, run qs_config.cmd, it will run an installer in which you'll have to enter a password for your server and please note that the port that worked for me is 7101 and 7102.

After the installer finishes, it will automatically run startWebLogic.cmd.
Wait until you see line like this: "<Sep 27, 2023 11:16:55,443 PM EET>    ".

I hope the answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

No need to follow all the above steps. Just goto Run --> Start server instance option in JDev. It will start and display success message in the console.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and some errors appeared related to keystore location and jre not found, I solved them but now this error appears: `Error: Could not find or load main class Elagroudy\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\DefaultDomain`. What is the class that he can't find?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).